# Obtain Administrators On Powershell to CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, administrator

I have been given the task to pull administrator information from different OU groups within active directory. I have been given a PowerShell code to run however always comes back with red errors and takes a long time to throw me a CSV file with nothing in it. I have limited PowerShell experience and any help would be grateful.

`$GPComputers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=OU=,DC=,DC=Local" -Filter * | where {Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.DNSHostName -count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}`
`$GPComputers | % { $a = $_ $Members = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $a.DNSHostname -ScriptBlock{Get-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators'} $AllMembers += $Members $Members = $null`
}
`$AllMembers | export-csv c:\temp\LocalAdmins.csv -NoType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding members to an undefined variable `$AllMembers`.
Apart from that, adding to an array with `+=` is very wasteful, because the **entire** array needs to be rebuilt completely in memory on each iteration.
Better let PowerShell do the collecting for you:

```
# set the credentials for admin access on the servers
$cred    = Get-Credential 'Please enter your admin credentials'

$GPComputers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=OU=,DC=,DC=Local" -Filter * 
$AllMembers = $GPComputers | ForEach-Object { 
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.DNSHostName -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        # simply output the result with added 'ComputerName' property ro be collected in variable '$AllMembers'
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.DNSHostname -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
            Get-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators' |
            Select-Object *, @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$($_.DNSHostName)' is not responding"
    }
} 

# remove the extra properties PowerShell added and save to CSV
$AllMembers | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunSpaceId | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\LocalAdmins.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for the help . I have added the OU and DC. I don't require credentials as I run as the Administrator. I Ran the code however looks like the admin prompt causes issue. Is there any further information I need to input apart from changing the OU.

Comment: What do you mean by `the admin prompt causes issue`? and `I run as the Administrator` means you run the script using Run as Administrator? That won't help, because you need permissions on the machines you are probing, not just your local machine.

Comment: I will try a few things and report back.

Comment: So Looking promising I have changed the OU and Added my Admin credentials as it requests. It Then looks like its running a scan throughout the OU computers. I get a lot of no responding potential due to Get-LocalGroupMember requires PowerShell 5.1 to be on the client computer, so older machines will not report back and get various errors but I will let it do its run.

Comment: @Ozzy.M1 Ah.. you should have said there were older machines in the environment. I'm on mobile now, but can give an alternative to `Get-LocalGroupMember` for computers that don't support that

Comment: A Massive Thank You Theo Life safer and Legend. I Think it all worked a treat.

Comment: Thanks again Theo I don't think I require an alternative.